# HBase on docker NotServingRegionException because of hostname alisas

Tags: hadoop, docker, hbase

I am building a fully distributed hbase cluster with unmanaged zookeeper.
I pretty much used this example and install hbase on top of it: https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker

Hadoop and hdfs works fine but I get this exception with hbase:

```
2016-09-05 06:27:12,268 INFO  [hadoop-master:16000.activeMasterManager] zookeeper.MetaTableLocator: Failed verification of hbase:meta,,1 at address=hadoop-slave2,16020,1473052276351, exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online on hadoop-slave2.hadoopnet,16020,1473056813966
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2910)
```

This is bloking because any command I enter on the hbase shell will return the following error:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
```

The containers are runned using --net=hadoopnet
which is a network create as such:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge hadoopnet
```

The hbase webui is showing this:

```
Region Servers
ServerName  Start time  Version Requests Per Second Num. Regions
hadoop-slave1,16020,1473056814064   Mon Sep 05 06:26:54 UTC 2016    1.2.2   0   0
hadoop-slave1.hadoopnet,16020,1473056814064 Mon Sep 05 06:26:54 UTC 2016    Unknown 0   0
hadoop-slave2,16020,1473056813966   Mon Sep 05 06:26:53 UTC 2016    1.2.2   0   0
hadoop-slave2.hadoopnet,16020,1473056813966 Mon Sep 05 06:26:53 UTC 2016    Unknown 0   0
Total:4     2 nodes with inconsistent version   0   0
```

I should have only 2 regionservers but 2 strange hadoop-slave1.hadoopnet and hadoop-slave2.hadoopnet are added to the list.
When I look at zk using:

```
/usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase zkcli -server zk:2181 ls /hbase/rs
```

I only see my 2 regionserver: hadoop-slave1,16020,1473056814064 and hadoop-slave2,16020,1473056813966

Looking at the zookeeper.MetaTableLocator: Failed verification error I see that  hadoop-slave2,16020,1473052276351 and hadoop-slave2.hadoopnet,16020,1473056813966 get mixed up.

here is my config on all server

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

    <configuration>
      <property>
            <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/hbase</value>
          <description>The directory shared by region servers. Should be fully-qualified to include the filesystem to use. E.g: hdfs://NAMENODE_SERVER:PORT/HBASE_ROOTDIR</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.master</name>
          <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:60000</value>
          <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
          <value>true</value>
          <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
          false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
          true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
          <value>60010</value>
          <description>The UI interface of HBase master runs.</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
          <value>zk</value>
          <description>string m_e_m_b_e_r_s is replaced by list of hosts separated by comma. Its generated by configure-slaves.sh on master node</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
          <value>300</value>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.datadir</name>
          <value>/tmp/zookeeper</value>
          <description>location of storage of zookeeper data</description>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
          <value>2181</value>
      </property>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? We also are using Hbase with docker and are running into this issue while restarting the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, env as below :

- hadoop 2.7.2
- hbase 1.2.2
- zookeeper 3.4.8

It came to my attention, that the `hbase-1.2.2` included hadoop's jar as `2.5.1`, zookeeper's jar as `3.4.6`, I upgraded them to the version i'm using (hadoop & zookeeper), the error has gone, but still found `[hostname].[docker-network]` as a region-server, except this, everything is fine.